# Passing Model Data to JSON in ASP.NET MVC (returning null)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json

I have this code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(BMICalculation CalculateBMI)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            CalculateBMI.Id = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            CalculateBMI.Date = System.DateTime.Now;
            CalculateBMI.BMICalc = CalculateBMI.CalculateMyBMI(CalculateBMI.Weight, CalculateBMI.Height);
            CalculateBMI.BMIMeaning = CalculateBMI.BMIInfo(CalculateBMI.BMICalc);
            ShowBMI(CalculateBMI.ToString());
            db.BMICalculations.Add(CalculateBMI);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return View();
    }

    public JsonResult ShowBMI(string BMICalculation){
        BMICalculation BMI = new BMICalculation();
        var data = new
        {
            BMICalculation
        };
        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I want the BMI calculation to be passed from the Create(BMICalculation CalculateBMI) method to the ShowBMI method so that it can be then passed to my webpage as a Json value.

The javascript function is called by submit button (which also processes the form):

```
  <button type="submit" id="submit" onclick="ShowBMI();"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save"></span></button>
```

And my JS is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function ShowBMI() {
        $.getJSON('/BMICalculations/ShowBMI', function (data) {
            alert(data.BMICalculation);
        });
    });

</script>
```

When I click the submit button an alert appears saying null even though I have values in my webpage textboxes. Is there a way around this in my controller?

Update 1 - So I've changed my Create() code but now I dont understand ' and then change your code so that you do an Ajax POST, with your serialized form'

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public JsonResult Create(BMICalculation CalculateBMI)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            CalculateBMI.Id = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            CalculateBMI.Date = System.DateTime.Now;
            CalculateBMI.BMICalc = CalculateBMI.CalculateMyBMI(CalculateBMI.Weight, CalculateBMI.Height);
            CalculateBMI.BMIMeaning = CalculateBMI.BMIInfo(CalculateBMI.BMICalc);
            db.BMICalculations.Add(CalculateBMI);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        var data = new
        {
            BMICalculation = CalculateBMI.BMICalc,
            BMIInfo = CalculateBMI.BMIMeaning
        };

        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, when you are clicking the submit button, you are actually performing two requests, unaware of eachother:

- One regular form post, that's processed, and returns with the view.
- An Ajax GET request, that gets some data from ShowBMI on your controller. This Action requires a `string` and since you're not passing it any data, it returns null.

Again, if I understood you correctly, the scenario you want to achieve is that when you POST your form, you want a Json payload back with the processed result. 
If that is correct, then what you'd probably want to do in have your Create action return the Json , and then change your code so that you do an Ajax POST, with your serialized form.Then in your Ajax `success` handler process the result you get back, just like you're doing now. I hope my intent is clear, otherwise, please ask for clarification. :)

Comment: Hi yes you do understand correctly. I've changed my create action to return a JsonResult. What do you mean by Ajax POST with serialised form? And Ajax success handler? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the required parameters to the method in controller...

You should try something like this..

```
 function ShowBMI() {


                    $.ajax({

                        url: "@Url.Action("Create", "Your Controller")",
                        data: {
                            'CalculateBMI': your Data
                        },
                        dataType: 'json',
                        type: 'POST',
                        success: function (response) {
                            try {

                              alert(response.BMICalculation);

                            }
                            catch (error) {

                            }
                        },
                        error: function () {

                        }
                    });
                   }
```

Comment: Does this code replace any of my existing code or should I use this in combination?

Comment: Also, if im already posting the parameters to the form using HttpPost why do I need to pass them again using AJAX?

Comment: You are not passing the parameters in the code you posted. You can use this code in combination.I think you can replace your `ShowBMI()` function using this script. Beware of syntax errors like missing brackets ;)

Comment: Ok so whats meant by 'CalculateBMI':your Data?

Comment: Am i mistaking paramenters to mean something other than weight and height? They are passed through to the Create method using HttpPost and FormMethod.Post into the controller upon submit clicking.

Comment: you should pass the textbox values as you mentioned above to the method. Just put a break point and check whether you get textbox values as the parameters.

Comment: Ok yeah I get the correct parameters from the form using httppost. But help me understand the full purpose of your function and what it aims to do?

Comment: By using ajax you can do partial updates to the page without posting back the page. No need to reload the whole page again.So to call the method using ajax you have to pass the required parameters through ajax.

Comment: Ok so the 'Your data' is the values of my height and weight textboxes? Or am i mistaken?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54912/discussion-between-tarzanbappa-and-aspcoder1450).

Answer (score 0):

Use With

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(BMICalculation CalculateBMI)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           return Json(obj, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
           return View();
        }
    }
```

You can get the method using ActionResult and return it with Json Obejct also